# Cisco Virtual Wireless Controller and Vmware Promiscuous mode

Tags: cisco, vmware-esxi, wifi, vmware-vsphere

I have read every post and guide in regards to deployment of cisco vWLC. Only part I dont understand is that they make it a huge point that promiscuous mode must be enabled on the vSwitch or in my case port group.

[Cisco vWLC deployment](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps12723/products_tech_note09186a0080bd2d04.shtml)

[Random post similar question](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2213235)

I dont have any free NICS on my ESXi hosts for a new vswitch. Also I dont want to enable promiscuous on a new port group on one of my existing vSwitchs since it will allow it to see all traffic in that vswitch (much unrelated wireless traffic).

I was wondering if anyone has run a similar configuration or has a recommendation?

(i wont be using the service port)

**Edit: Just to be clear, if I could get more NICS i would. Everything is taken, including expansion slots**

Comment: Get ***MOAR*** NICs!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation would be to purchase additional NICs as needed to support this properly.

Comment: Thought of that. I am Tapped out for ports and expansion slots at this time.

Comment: Well, that's the limit of your hardware... Unless you're prepared to trunk your vSwitch uplinks.

Comment: I'd STRONGLY suggest you do as MDMarra suggests, even if this means swapping out single or double-NIC adapters for double or quad ones. There's nothing else I'd suggest.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that but NP then. Everything else about setup was piece of cake.

Comment: Those quad NICs are super cheap these days - unless you're talking about 40/100Gbps ones of course :)

Comment: Well in my situation both expansion slots are taken by two dual 10Gps. The 1Gps stuff is onboard. I will figure something out.

Comment: What server make/model is it? We're pretty good at HW issues here